# Watch for stateParams in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to apply a CSS style in an element within a certain route. For this I  have created a directive where I add the class when $state.include includes the location, but since the path keeps changing it needs to watch for changes in the $state, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
angular
    .module('pharm')
    .directive('flApplyStyle',['$stateParams','$state',applyStyle]);

function applyStyle($stateParams,$state) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            console.log($state.current);
            scope.$watch($stateParams, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if ($state.includes("app.calc.edit")) {
                    element.addClass('BackgroundEdit');
                }else{
                    element.addClass('none');
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work. Tap into the `$stateChangeStart` event and then check for changes to `$state`. If that event doesn't work, try `$stateChangeSuccess`.

```
angular
    .module('pharm')
    .directive('flApplyStyle', ['$rootScope','$state', applyStyle]);

function applyStyle($rootScope, $state) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
                if ($state.includes("app.calc.edit")) {
                    element.addClass('BackgroundEdit');
                } else {
                    element.addClass('none');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```